# Edited part needs to be focusable?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

While accessing **DeveloperStory**<sup>Beta</sup> I tried to add data regarding my `Position` but what I found is when I save the form or cancel the form then it looses its focus and left me where that forms end lie. This is not with that particular `Position` part but it behaves same with each form on that page the particular part didn't stayed focusable.

The issue is when I click on <kbd>**edit**</kbd> button as shown in the followed pic

[image]

It opens me up a form which looks like as

[image]

Looks ok till I clicks <kbd>**Cancel**</kbd> or  <kbd>**save**</kbd> cause when I click one of those buttons it losses it focus towards the `div` what it shows to me is

[image]

Instead it should show me

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding the issue. Could you add screenshots and explain what you did in a few steps? Thanks

Comment: @Stéphane I tried my best to explain my issue even though it seems trouble to you then revert me on the same